How to read vactor/map of vectors from a config file with boost program_options?
Is it possible to read vector or map of vectors from configuration file with boost program_options?
Starting from a configuration file that looks like:
[Lorems]
lorem.1=Lorem ipsum
lorem.1=dolor sit amet,
lorem.1=consectetur adipiscing elit,
lorem.2=Risus ad himenaeos tempor convallis habitasse. 
lorem.2=At diam erat odio nisl malesuada curae.

I need to read them in a vector or map variable containing vectors with the settings:
lorems[0] = { "Lorem ipsum", "dolor sit amet,", "consectetur adipiscing elit," }
lorems[1] = { "Risus ad himenaeos tempor convallis habitasse.", "At diam erat odio nisl malesuada curae." }

I can't find a way. I have noticed a behavior, though. By using this setup:
...
void validate(boost::any& v,
    const std::vector<std::string>& s,
    std::vector<Mock>*,
    int) {

    if (v.empty()) {
        v = boost::any(std::vector<Mock>());
    }
    std::vector<Mock>* tv = boost::any_cast<std::vector<Mock>>(&v);
    assert(NULL != tv);
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < s.size(); ++i)
    {
        try {                
            boost::any a;
            Mock cv;
            cv.push_back(s[i]);
            validate(a, cv, (Mock*)0, 0);                
            tv->push_back(boost::any_cast<Mock>(a));
        }
        catch(const boost::bad_lexical_cast& /*e*/) {
            throw po::validation_error(po::validation_error::invalid_option_value);
        }
    }
}
...
class Lorem: public std::vector<std::string> {};
...
Lorem lorem = Lorem();
...
file_options.add_options()
  ("Lorems.lorem.*", po::value<std::vector<std::string>(&lorems)->composing(), "Lorems")
  ;
...

the last vector read is contained in the variable, i.e.:
lorems = { "Risus ad himenaeos tempor convallis habitasse.", "At diam erat odio nisl malesuada curae." }
Adding a new dimension (sort of) will fail compiling, so I can't check further.
...
class Lorem: public std::vector<std::string> {};
...
std::vector<Lorem> lorems = std::vector<Lorem>();
...
file_options.add_options()
  ("Lorems.lorem.*", po::value<std::vector<Lorem>>(&lorems)->composing(), "Lorems")
  ;
...

The error is in value_semantic.hpp:
'boost::program_options::validate': overloaded functions have similar conversions.

Same if I directly work with std::vectorstd::vector<std::string>>.
I've tried to write a validate function (as a stub of code), it used it, yet, can't match the key with it and, despite it compiles, throws a linkage error that it already exists (in the boost library...).
As a side note, an alias like Lorem for the std::vectorstd::string is needed to implement a formatting function that would not be applied to std::vectorstd::strings variables, but only to Lorem ones.
What is the right way to achieve this goal of reading a collection of vectors from a config file with boost program_options?
